# packer to bake AMI from shared AMI and Share with other AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, packer, ec2-ami

I am trying to create AMI with (shared AMI from another Account). since i do not have access to snapshot i cannot create or rename AMI so i opted to use Packer to Bake New AMI with needed custom Name.

Since Shared AMI is encrypted so the newly created AMI its created with default AWS Key due to this i cannot share AMI with other accounts.

`(error msg: ==> amazon-ebs.instance: Error modify AMI attributes: InvalidParameter: Snapshots encrypted with the AWS Managed CMK can't be shared. Specify another snapshot)`

need some advice on how to address this issue.

P.S i need to create new AMI with custom name from Shared AMI so i can share same AMI across AWS Accounts.

i am open for hearing alternate approach also.